# "/trunk/Classes/../iTunesArtwork: No such file or directory" on Build or Run after upgrading to xCode 4.3 from 3.2.5

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4, itunesartwork

After upgrading to xCode 4.3 today I can't build or run one of my 3.2.5 projects because of the following build error:

> CpResource Classes/../iTunesArtwork /Users/glen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-bfsepykuktirdfeuvqhjyyiuhqii/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project.app/iTunesArtwork
>       cd /Users/glen/Dev/Project/trunk
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks -strip-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip /Users/glen/Dev/Project/trunk/Classes/../iTunesArtwork /Users/glen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-bfsepykuktirdfeuvqhjyyiuhqii/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project.app
>
> **error: /Users/glen/Dev/Project/trunk/Classes/../iTunesArtwork: No such file or directory**

There are a [few mentions](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=iTunesArtwork:+No+such+file+or+directory+xcode+build+fail+upgrade+from+xcode+3+to+xcode+4&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) of this error around the internet, most of them referring to Ad Hoc builds and adding application icons post-build.

[As suggested here](http://codeandbutter.com/2011/01/including-itunesartwork-in-ad-hoc-distributions/), I've tried adding iTunesArtwork as a resource to the top level of the project as a 512x512png, which gives a build warning stating:

> Check dependencies
>
> Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/glen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-bfsepykuktirdfeuvqhjyyiuhqii/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project.app/iTunesArtwork

followed by the early failure error.
I know I have to get rid of this reference to iTunesArtwork somehow, but I'm not sure where to start looking or where this error is stemming from.

I am using a local svn repository from which I imported the project, which I haven't used with xCode 4, which might be part of the problem, but I'm not sure.

I am attempting to build using the iOS 5 SDK for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was that some files, including iTunesArtwork, didn't come across properly from the repository. I found the references to these files and removed them, and built successfully.

Comment: i have the same issue, but with *.png files that i deleted and xcode keep looking to copy them :error: /some-path/star-48.png: No such file or directory, any ideas?

Comment: If you're using svn there is a bug where you sometimes have to add them again and then remove them. Really annoying. I changed to a git repo instead of svn and the problem stopped.

Comment: actually using git (github, and i guess also xcodes by default), i jsut gave back and put a dummy files in the root project folder for now.